# Hide View but still show UIWebView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview

I have a UIWebView in a view but what i want to do is hide the background but still show the UIWebView. Im new to Mobile development. I have researched and used code from net but cannot find a solution can anyone please help. Thanks.

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^() {
            view.alpha = 0.0;
        }];
```

I have got the UIWebView to fade out but thats not what i want, basically the UIWebView still needs to be visible but the background to be faded out or make the background hidden but not the UIWebView

I have also tried:

```
[UIView beginAnimations: @"Fade Out" context:nil];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:2.0];
        [self.view setAlpha:0.0f];
        [UIView commitAnimations];
```

Seems to only fade out the UIWebView

Comment: Please post the code you have

Comment: who is view that u set his alpha to 0.0???

Comment: seems like its the UIWebView because the UIWebView seems to fade out

Comment: @redoc01 please read my answer and see is this the issue

Answer (score 1):

You are setting the alpha on the view itself, which will be applied to the view and its subviews. Change its background color

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.3f animations:^{
   view.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
}];
```

Comment: self.view.layer.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor].CGColor; this line errors saying unknown backgroundColor property

Comment: @redoc01 sorry forgot to mention to import `#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>` and remember to add the framework

Comment: Thanks simon, im still trying to add the framework on xcode 3.2.6 but dont know how to add it

Comment: Why do you set view's layer background color instead of view's background color ?

Comment: Hi simon thanks again, i added the framework ran the app but still the background stays white does not hide

Comment: @redoc01 What exactly is behind the view that you are hoping to see? How will you know if the view's background is hidden or not?

Comment: @daveMac basically there is a uitableview when i select an item in the tablecell another view slides up and this view has the UIWebview now i want to hide the background containing the UIWebView but dont want to hide the UIWebview. Once the background is hidden i want to be able to see the UITableView

Comment: @redoc01 Have you tried not adding the web view and seeing if the background is indeed clear? Also, I'm not sure why you need to delve down to the CALayer level. Just set the views background color like so: view.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

Comment: ive got macbook air has limitaions cannot upgrade so im stuck with using 3.2.6

Comment: @redoc01 What crashed the app? Removing the view or changing the color?

Comment: @daveMac removing the layer property

Comment: @redoc01 Did you leave the .CGColor? The snippet I gave you shouldn't crash the app, since I've used it literally hundreds of times in my apps.

Comment: @daveMac i removed the .CGColor now and it didnt crash the app but still the background is white and still cannot see the other view with the tableview

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47782/discussion-between-davemac-and-redoc01)

Comment: @daveMac hi dave, ive just purchased a Mac Mini and i have opened the project in Xcode 5 and ran the project, but still can't seem to make the background which is solid white, transparent so the other view with the tableview is shown